# I just created a new RN project expecting to get version .66 but have a tar.gz instead

Tags: react-native, expo

My package.json has the following line where a RN version number should be, does anyone know what this means and if it can be replaced with the correct version?

`"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",`

I created the project with:

`expo init Project-Name`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you created the project with Expo. You now have an Expo "Managed" app. Read more about it here: https://docs.expo.dev/
Expo has some requirements of its own. This article explains why Expo is never going to be on the latest version of React Native: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/react-native-releases.md

If you didn't want Expo, you can "eject" to a "bare" Expo app, or just start over with the React Native CLI as described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. (you have to be careful to select the "React Native CLI Quickstart" tab in the setup instructions)